# WoW Interface Addon - Hide and Show Button

Tags: button, interface, lua, add-on, world-of-warcraft

I have some problems with coding a simple interface addon for World of Warcraft.
I'm trying to achieve the following: I want to display a button if one of my spells has no cooldown. If I click the button then the spell should cast and the button should hide during the cooldown time.

The cast is working fine, but I have problems to hide the button. I always get an error message in chat after clicking. Here is my code:

TestAddon.toc

```
## Interface: 60000
## Title: TestAddon
## Notes: Test
## Version: 1.0
TestAddon.lua
```

TestAddon.lua

```
btn_schutz = CreateFrame("Button", "MyButton", UIParent, "SecureActionButtonTemplate");
btn_schutz:ClearAllPoints();
btn_schutz:SetAttribute("type", "spell");
btn_schutz:SetAttribute("spell", "Schutz"); -- Schutz is name of spell (German)
btn_schutz:SetAttribute("unit", "player");
btn_schutz:SetPoint("CENTER", 0, 0);
btn_schutz:SetNormalTexture("Interface\\Icons\\ability_monk_guard");
btn_schutz:SetSize(48, 48);
btn_schutz:SetScript("OnUpdate", onUpdate);
btn_schutz:Show();

function onUpdate()
    local schutz_id = 115295;
    if GetSpellCooldown(schutz_id) == 0 then
        btn_schutz:Show(); -- causes error message
    else
        btn_schutz:Hide(); -- causes error message
    end
end
```

Comment: "Failed performing an action of interface because of an addon", but I translated it into English, so it isn't literally.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're getting a standard taint error.  Read more about it here: [Secure Execution and Tainting](http://wowpedia.org/Secure_Execution_and_Tainting)

You cannot show or hide buttons (or any "secure" frame) while your character is in combat.